# Issue with Virtual PC XP Image

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

I created a Win XP SP3 Virtual Image in a PC running Win XP SP3 using Microsoft Virtual PC 2007. The image works fine in XP. Now I copied the same XP SP3 Image to a Win 7 PC and installed MS Virtual PC 2007 and tried to load the image, but it gives boot failure.

File was copied correctly and there are no issues. Please assist.

Comment: what do you mean by created a Win XP SP3 Virtual Image in a PC running Win XP SP3 using Microsoft Virtual PC 2007.

Comment: you have installed wind xp sp3 in Microsoft Virtual PC 2007 right.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Yes, I created the Xp Sp3 image using Virtual PC 2007. This images starts and works properly in Windows XP. But if i copy the same image and try it on a host PC which has Windows 7 with the same Virtual PC 2007, it gives the boot failure during booting.